# Proof that a group is a group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

Hi all I'm stuck on a homework question. The question is as follows:

"For $a,b\in\mathbb R$ we define $a∗b:=a+b+ab\in\mathbb R$. Furthermore let $G =\mathbb R\setminus\{-1\}$.

Show  that  $G$  together  with  the binary  operation $G × G → G, (a, b)  → a ∗ b$, is a group"

I know I must show that it's associative, there exists a neutral element and there exists an inverse. So far I've managed to show it's associative and I think the neutral element is letting $b=0$ but I don't know what the inverse element would be so that $a*b=0$. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you denote $R/-1$?

Comment: Your question's title is funny...

Comment: All of the deals excluding -1

Comment: All of the reals excluding -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: remember that $\;a\neq-1\;$:

$$0=a*a':=a+a'+aa'=a+(1+a)a'$$

Comment: More exactly, $a\ne -1$.

Comment: Of course how'd I miss that

Comment: @BernardGood catch on that typo, thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the inverse to a given $a\in G$ corresponds to finding the solution of the equation $a+x+ax=0$ with $a\in G$ being a parameter and $x \in G$ the unknown, so you get:

$a+x+ax=0$

$x(1+a)=-a$

$x= \frac{-a}{1+a}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Don't forget you have to show this is an *internal* law.

Rewriting $a*b$ as $(a+1)(b+1)-1$, finding a inverse amounts to solving 
$$(a+1)(b+1)=1.$$